# how to add own images in mapview balloon

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add an image in mapview balloon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578388/how-to-add-an-image-in-mapview-balloon)

this is a code which show image from url how do i give image from my res/drawable folder? this is a https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons  code i used please tell me how i give my own images istead of url

```
 public class CustomMap extends MapActivity {

MapView mapView;
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
Drawable drawable;
Drawable drawable2;
CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> itemizedOverlay;
CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> itemizedOverlay2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    // first overlay
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
    itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(drawable,  
   mapView);

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(51.5174723*1E6),(int)(-0.0899537*1E6));
    CustomOverlayItem overlayItem = new CustomOverlayItem(point, "Tomorrow  
   Never Dies (1997)", 
            "(M gives Bond his mission in Daimler car)", 
            "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images 
 5BMTM1MTk2ODQxNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTY5MDg0NA@@._V1._SX40_CR0,0,40,54_.jpg");
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

    GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint((int)(51.515259*1E6),(int)(-0.086623*1E6));
    CustomOverlayItem overlayItem2 = new CustomOverlayItem(point2,  
    "GoldenEye    (1995)", 
            "(Interiors Russian defence ministry council chambers in  
St Petersburg)", 
            "http://ia.media-imdb.com 


  images5BMzk2OTg4MTk1NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNj
ExNTgzNA@@._V1._SX40_CR0,0,40,54_.jpg");        
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem2);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    // second overlay
    drawable2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker2);
    itemizedOverlay2 = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>
   (drawable2,    mapView);

    GeoPoint point3 = new GeoPoint((int)(51.513329*1E6),(int)(-0.08896*1E6));
    CustomOverlayItem overlayItem3 = new CustomOverlayItem(point3, "Sliding 
   Doors (1998)", 
            "(interiors)", null);
    itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(overlayItem3);

    GeoPoint point4 = new GeoPoint((int)(51.51738*1E6),(int)(-0.08186*1E6));
    CustomOverlayItem overlayItem4 = new CustomOverlayItem(point4, "Mission:  
  Impossible (1996)", 
            "(Ethan & Jim cafe meeting)", 
            "http://ia.media- 
      imdb.coimagesV5BMjAyNjk5Njk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOT
 A4MjIyMQ@@._V1._SX40_CR0,0,40,54_.jpg");       
    itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(overlayItem4);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);

    final MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.animateTo(point2);
    mc.setZoom(16);

  }

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

         }







                     public class CustomOverlayItem extends OverlayItem {

protected String mImageURL;

public CustomOverlayItem(GeoPoint point, String title, String snippet, String  
         imageURL) {
    super(point, title, snippet);
    mImageURL = imageURL;
}

public String getImageURL() {
    return mImageURL;
}

public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
    this.mImageURL = imageURL;
}

             }




                    public class CustomBalloonOverlayView<Item extends OverlayItem> 
       extends BalloonOverlayView<CustomOverlayItem> {

private TextView title;
private TextView snippet;
private ImageView image;

public CustomBalloonOverlayView(Context context, int balloonBottomOffset) {
    super(context, balloonBottomOffset);
}

@Override
protected void setupView(Context context, final ViewGroup parent) {

    // inflate our custom layout into parent
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.balloon_overlay_example2, parent);

    // setup our fields
    title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.balloon_item_title);
    snippet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.balloon_item_snippet);
    image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.balloon_item_image);

}

@Override
protected void setBalloonData(CustomOverlayItem item, ViewGroup parent) {

    // map our custom item data to fields
    title.setText(item.getTitle());
    snippet.setText(item.getSnippet());

    // get remote image from network.
    // bitmap results would normally be cached, but this is good enough for  
         demo purpose.
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
    new FetchImageTask() { 
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (result != null) {
                image.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }
    }.execute(item.getImageURL());

}

private class FetchImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        Bitmap b = null;
        try {
             b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new  
       URL(arg0[0]).getContent());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return b;
    }   
}

     }
```

Comment: Don't create same question many time just because you dont have an answer. I check your profile and there're 8 question but they're identical. If you see some answer is useful, Remember to tick the mark at the left of the answer to set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way

1. Change `CustomOverlayItem` class. If you don't want load image from URL, you can change  `String mImageURL` to `int drawableId`. And create getter and setter for this variable and new contructor.

   ```
   public class CustomOverlayItem extends OverlayItem {

   protected String mImageURL;
   private int drawableId;



   public CustomOverlayItem(GeoPoint point, String title, String snippet, int drawableId) {
       super(point, title, snippet);
       this.drawableId = drawableId;
   }

   public CustomOverlayItem(GeoPoint point, String title, String snippet, String imageURL) {
       super(point, title, snippet);
       mImageURL = imageURL;
   }


   public int getDrawableId() {
       return drawableId;
   }

   public void setDrawableId(int drawableId) {
       this.drawableId = drawableId;
   }

   public String getImageURL() {
       return mImageURL;
   }

   public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
       this.mImageURL = imageURL;
   }
   ```

   }
2. In `setBalloonData` method of `CustomBalloonOverlayView` class, change it to

   ```
   @Override
   protected void setBalloonData(CustomOverlayItem item, ViewGroup parent) {

   // map our custom item data to fields
   title.setText(item.getTitle());
   snippet.setText(item.getSnippet());

   // get remote image from network.
   // bitmap results would normally be cached, but this is good enough for demo purpose.
   image.setImageResource(item.getDrawableId()); // you set your image from drawable here.

   Here is where you load image from URL. So comment or remove it.
   /*new FetchImageTask() { 
       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
           if (result != null) {
               image.setImageBitmap(result);
           }
        }
   }.execute(item.getImageURL());*/ }
   ```
3. In `CustomMap`, change the way you create overlay

   ```
    CustomOverlayItem overlayItem = new CustomOverlayItem(point, "Tomorrow Never Dies (1997)", 
               "(M gives Bond his mission in Daimler car)", 
               R.drawable.marker); // pass your drawable here  instead of URL.
   ```

If you want to keep method load URL, you must modify `BalloonOverlayView` too.

Comment: wow thats great its solve thank u soo much now finnaly u give corect answer

Comment: thanx aloe u did great job Sir